# PHP prepare and execute

Tags: php, mysql

I was using the following code to execute the queries in the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cc_topchoices  WHERE location='$location' ORDER BY position asc";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

I have read that this way to make the queries is not secure so I want to use the statements `prepare()` and `execute()` in php
Now my code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cc_topchoices WHERE location=:location ORDER BY position asc";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(":location" => $location));

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);
```

But this give me this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Any idea?

**EDIT**

Now my code looks like this:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", "$username", "$password");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("set names utf8"); //BECAUSE I NEED TO WORK WITH CHINESE LANGUAGE

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cc_topchoices WHERE location=? ORDER BY position asc";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':location', $location);
$stmt->execute(array($location));           
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($result > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<li><div><a href='". $row["rest_url"] ."'><img src='images/top_choices/". $row["image"] ."' alt='". $row["alt_desc"]. "' /></a></div></li>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

is working :) just need to know if this is a good and secure practice

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up PDO and mysqli and have assembled something from random sources around the interwebs. I'd suggest you go read the official manual for the database connector you're using (mysqli) instead.

Comment: Everybody refers to the documentation in their answers or comments but maybe the OP doesn't know where to find it. Here it is: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: hey I made a mix between you answer and edited my question... is working now, this is a secure a good practice? I am completely new in php

Comment: @TomasLucena You can get rid of the `$stmt->bindParam(':location', $location);` bit in your new code. It's not doing anything as you're no longer using named parameters in your prepared sql.

Answer (score 5):

PDO supports named parameters. MySQLi does not. `$stmt` is `false` to show you that the SQL you tried to prepare is syntactically malformed. Use `?` instead of `:location`. Check the MySQLi manual for the correct way to use MySQLi. Or, alternately, switch to PDO.

Comment: can you check my edit and let me know if looks secure now?

Comment: As long as you use parameter binding and not direct concatenation with raw inputs, it is secure (whether with MySQLi or PDO). I did not check whether the syntax is correct, but at first glance looks good. If it works, you're okay.

Answer (score -2):

Use below code to fetch records instead of mysqli_query when using pdo statements if your query returns single row.

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result['db_column'];
```

And if return multiple rows:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $result['db_column'];
    }
```

And one more thing, always put your prepared statement in try{}..catch{} block.
It will work for you.

Comment: This doesn't help OP. The process fails before getting to the point you're trying to explain.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should have seen the error closely before directly go for answer. But Applying my answer also removes the error and solve the problem.

Comment: yes, I mix your answer with other ones and is working... thanks

Comment: Actually it helped @JonStirling. Thanks for your downvote.

Comment: @KetanJoshi Being helpful for something separate to the original issue might seem good, but it doesn't make the answer better. It is still my opinion that this is not a useful (or even relevant) answer for the issue that was posted. You disagree, that's fine. Down votes lose the downvoter rep too, so it's not like it's just a vote for the sake of it.

Comment: @JonStirling I do not disagree with your comment that states"The process fails before getting to the point you're trying to explain." I have mentioned it in earlier comment too. But i am disagree with you pointed out in same comment that " This doesn't help OP."

Comment: @KetanJoshi Fine, it helped the OP, but not with the problem they were actually having, only by chance. The answer is still, imo, not helpful wrt to the actual issue. Therefore, downvote.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you. Learned a lession.